# Windows 7 32 bit application on Win 10 docker

Tags: windows, docker

Is it possible to create a windows 7 32 bit image and run it on the windows 10 64-bit machine using docker desktop?
Do we have any official windows 7 32 bit ready docker base images?

Can any one please help.

The requirement is to run a windows 7 32 bit Visual basic application on the Windows 10 desktops. I thought of creating a Hyper-V and using Windows 7 32 bit VM… but before that I wanted to know if we can containerize this using docker.